# Pseudo English to Regexp

Tags: regex

Is there a translator from pseudo English to regexp? That is, a sort of scripting language to ouput regexp?
Thank you.
Tuba

Comment: Yes, and it's called Stack Overflow. (But seriously: the number of "I need a regex to do this" questions here has been rather overwhelming lately.)

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is [txt2re](http://txt2re.com/index-php.php3) or a similar tool.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, why would anyone not want to write their own regular expressions :)

There are tools (websites) that build regular expressions on a piece of text, but they require a fair amount of user input. Checkout this one:

http://boingboing.net/2011/04/14/automatically-genera.html

It sounds like you are looking for a rules engine (using it as an API in your code)? If that is the case, you should checkout Drools, it's very powerful and can do too much.

Comment: Writing regular expressions makes me want to check myself in the loony bin :) Thanks for the pointers.